# Why my code not giving compile error?

Tags: java

In the below code i am assigning data to final object .But not getting the compile error .

```
class Name {
    private String name;

    public Name (String s) {
        this.name = s;
    }

    public void setName(String s) {
        this.name = s;
    }
}

private void test (final Name n) {
    n.setName("test");//here exception coming but not giving compile error
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4):

> Once a final variable has been assigned, it always contains the same value. ***If a final variable holds a reference to an object, then the state of the object may be changed by operations on the object, but the variable will always refer to the same object.***

So it is OK to manipulate state of object pointed by `n`

```
private void test(final Name n) {
    n.setName("test");
}
```

but you can't make `n` to store another object

```
private void test(final Name n) {
    n = new Name("test"); //Can't do this
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Because `final` applies to the reference `n`, not the object that `n` refers to.

So you won't be able to do this:

```
n = new Name("test");
```